# Comparison between two longs doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, numbers

this will be a simple question (or at least i think). I have to compare a Long object to a long primitive.

My code simplified:

```
long primitiveLong = 285825645621;
Long objectLong = new Long(285825645621);

if(primitiveLong == objectLong.longValue()){
    System.out.print("They are equals");
}
```

I expected that it would have worked, but it didn't, can someone explain me why?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Ok, i did a mistake using explicit numbers, i'll put here my code:

```
long identifier = mMarkers.get(marker);
long currentId = item.getId().longValue();

if (currentId==identifier)
    System.out.print("They are equals");
```

**In debug**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

It was an IDE (Android Studio) bug in debug mode, i tried on another IDE and it worked well with same code. So thanks to everyone for the answers, but the problem was another, that i couldn't expect.

Comment: Should the code have entered the if loop or not or should we just take a guess about what you believe should have happened :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger The code should have entered in the if statement

Comment: It will not compile, For compilation add L in the end of number, then this code should work as-is @ChetanKinger `if` is not a loop but a statement;)

Answer (score 0):

First this must should give you compile error because compiler think of `285825645621` as an Integer but it is larger than int, so you need to change your code like this:

```
long primitiveLong = 285825645621l; //add and l at the end of your number so compiler know that it is a long not an int
Long objectLong = new Long(285825645621l); //do the same thing here

if(primitiveLong == objectLong.longValue()){
    System.out.print("They are equals");
}
```

and this will print : `They are equals`

Comment: As i said this is a more simplified version of my code. I haven't explicit numbers, but methods that return them

Comment: @Fondesa so you dont simplify your code well! please provide more information, with the data that you provided, I couldnt explain more about why that happened.

Comment: See the edits to my question!

Comment: @Fondesa are you sure you provide correct data now? they are both `long` with same value so `==` should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your literal value still this limit `285825645`

```
If you are using beyond the limit you will get compile error 

long primitiveLong = c;
            Long objectLong = new Long(285825645);

            if(primitiveLong == objectLong.longValue()){
                System.out.print("They are equals");
            }
```